Sprite Collision Detected But Snapping to Other Side of Collision Shape
Sprite Collision Detected But Snapping to Other Side of Collision Shape
My sprite / it's collision shape is colliding with my L and R walls, but if the cursor goes about half way through the shape it snaps the sprite to the other side of it. See here.
I was having a ton of trouble getting my sprite to collide at all, but then saw this post on Reddit. So I applied the "velocity * (1 / delta)" equation to move_and_collide() and it collides, but has some weird snapping issues.
extends CharacterBody2D

func _ready():
    pass
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    var mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
    self.position.x = mouse_pos.x
    move_and_collide(velocity * (1 / delta))


I tried making the collision shapes massive but the sprite snaps to the top of it instead of the other side. Not sure if i'm understanding move_and_collide(velocity * (1 / delta)) fully, so maybe knowing what this is doing exactly may help a bit. Took a look at the documentation for move_and_collide() and the result from velocity * (1 / delta) is the "motion" which would be the X-Axis positional value?
Regardless, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Setting the position of a CharacterBody2D directly is not ideal. In this case, the sprite is "teleporting" to the mouse position. If it teleports into a collision, it snaps to the nearest position where its own CollisionShape2D is not overlapping another. The ideal solution is to take advantage of move_and_collide().
move_and_collide()'s parameter is a Vector2 which essentially represents the displacement the body wants to move on the next physics update. The body adds this displacement to its position to move, unless a collision is detected along the displacement in which case the body moves until it is just colliding.
When using move_and_collide(), think about what the displacement should be. This is the difference between where the body wants to go and where it currently is. In your case, this correlates to the difference between the mouse's x-position and the body's current x-position. So, we can calculate this displacement and pass it as the x-component of the vector:
func _physics_process(delta):
    var mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
    var displacement = mouse_pos.x - position.x
    move_and_collide(Vector2(displacement, 0))

Note that the y-component of the vector is zero as we don't want to move vertically.
Now, if we move the mouse beyond one of the walls, a collision is detected along the displacement vector and the body moves up to the wall but not through/past it.

Perfect! I am eternally grateful for this answer :D

self.position.x = mouse_pos.x allows the CharacterBody2D to "teleport" along the x-axis. When it teleports onto a collision object, however, it will go to the nearest position it can where its own collision shape is not overlapping another (this is why making a collision shape wider may cause the sprite to "snap" to the top of it, as the shortest path to exit the collision is up).
If you want to prevent the sprite from moving outside of the area contained by the walls completely, you may want to use a WorldBoundaryShape2D for each wall. This will force the sprite to snap to the side that the shape's arm is on.
However, this may not behave well when setting position.x to the mouse's position directly, so you may instead want to simply define the bounds in your script and prevent the position from changing when the mouse is outside of them:
# x-positions of the left and right boundaries
const BOUNDARY_LEFT = -100 
const BOUNDARY_RIGHT = 100

func _physics_process(delta):
    var mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
    
    # Move to the mouse position if it is in-bounds
    if mouse_pos.x > BOUNDARY_LEFT and mouse_pos.x < BOUNDARY_RIGHT:
        self.position.x = mouse_pos.x
        

You can also add a safety net in case the mouse moves in and out of bounds faster than _physics_process() ticks:
# Move to the closest boundary if the mouse is out of bounds,
# otherwise move to the mouse's position.
if mouse_pos.x < BOUNDARY_LEFT:
    self.position.x = BOUNDARY_LEFT
elif mouse_pos.x > BOUNDARY_RIGHT:
    self.position.x = BOUNDARY_RIGHT
else:
    self.position.x = mouse_pos.x

As for move_and_collide(), the parameter is a Vector2 which essentially represents the displacement the body wants to move on this physics update, and if a collision is detected along this displacement the body does not move.
Passing velocity * (1 / delta) into move_and_collide() is the same as passing a zero vector, Vector2(0, 0), as the default velocity is zero and nothing in your script changes it. This is fine, as you are controlling the position of the body directly rather than its velocity, but you may want to just pass the zero vector or the typical velocity * delta to avoid any issues in the future.

Thank you! This actually worked a good amount and I appreciate the explanations a ton. Despite the boundaries being set, depending on house fast the mouse is traveling, it varies how far it stops from the boundary. So if I slowly bring the cursor to the boundary it stops at the set value, but moving it any faster makes it collide with seemingly invisible walls. Using a CS2D with the WorldBoundaryShape2D, the sprite collides correctly, but slowly phases through it.
I can probably combine methods here would work. Set the boundary to where the cursor would start to slow so it just stops.

@ouchers When using the conditional method, if the mouse is in bounds one frame and leaves the next frame, the body will remain where it was. I added a suggestion in the answer to fix this, but the best solution depends on what functionality you want.

Your suggestion worked perfectly! Thanks again :)

It's best to avoid setting the position like this in general, so I added another answer which is simpler and should work much better, and I recommend trying it out. I'll leave this answer up as it may be helpful for Static and Rigid bodies.
